# mod_wsgi на Windows Error 500

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Приветствую. Использую:

- Windows 10 64-bits
- Apache 2.4 VC14
- Python 3.6

Скачал скомпилированный пакет **mod_wsgi‑4.5.17+ap24vc14‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl** из данного [источника](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi)

Используя команду `pip install` установил данный пакет. С помощью команды

`mod_wsgi-express module-config` 
Получил следующий конфиг для апача:

```
LoadFile "c:/program files/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/program files/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/program files/python36"
```

Добавил его в **httpd.conf**. Запустил апач, открыл *localhost*, смотрю загловки ответа. Вижу там:
*Server:Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6*

Как я понимаю, это значит - что **mod_wsgi** успешно установился на **Apache**.
Добавляю в **httpd.conf**:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "D:/test/django.py"
<Directory "D:/test">
<Files django.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Содержимое файла **django.py** следующее:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Перезапустил апач, открыл *localhost/wsgi* и получил ошибку **500 Internal Server Error**
Иду в логи апача и там:

```
[Tue Aug 08 11:06:08.389722 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1228:tid 1260] [client ::1:54302] mod_wsgi (pid=1228): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/test/django.py'.
[Tue Aug 08 11:06:08.390722 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1228:tid 1260] [client ::1:54302] TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found\r
```

Может у кого есть идеи как исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Необходимо было возвращать не простую строку, то есть содержимое файла **django.py** должно быть следующим:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output.encode('UTF-8')]
```